# Are session variables in 'session' or 'user_session' in Rails with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise, session-variables

I want to store a non-critical non-confidential piece of information in the user's session in a Ruby on Rails app.  The user model is set up with Devise.  How do I do this?  Various guides give conflicting and incomplete information about it.  `session[:foo]`?  `user_session[:foo]`?  Do I need to set something up to be able to use whichever it is - e.g. get a gem, config something, or insert any lines before setting the session variable?

To provide context - the user may be creating multiple new items back-to-back, so it would be nice if the `new` form remembered and pre-selected the category based on what they selected previously.  If there's a better way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.  I'm new to all this.  Thank you!!

Comment: are you forcing the users to have the last items properties always? maybe you can just make a way to duplicate the item if they want to use the last items settings

Comment: Session is a bad database :) You can use in the form category input: `value: @current_user.items.last.category` (just a pseudocode, as I don't know what is the category, an attribute or an associated model)

Answer (score 2):

> Are session variables in 'session' or 'user_session' in Rails?

The simple answer is the session variables is named `session`.

A session usually consists of a hash of values and a session id, usually a 32-character string, to identify the hash. Every cookie sent to the client's browser includes the session id. And the other way round: the browser will send it to the server on every request from the client. In Rails you can save and retrieve values using the session method:

```
session[:cat_id] = cat_id
Category.find(session[:cat_id])
```

You can read this [`Rails Guide`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.1/security.html#sessions) about session.

[`ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I looked at that guide but was still confused as to whether or not it required some sort of activation or configuration before using.  Does it?

Answer (score 1):

The default Rails session object is accessible via the `session` helper method. It gives you an access to some chunks of data and is bound to a cookie value stored in your browser.

The `user_session` helper is provided by the Devise gem. It gives you additional security by restricting access to specific session data while user is authenticated on a server.